# How do I create access control rules from code for an azure cloud service?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a network access control list in my cloud service similar to the below. How do I configure this programmatically instead of from the config file?

Some of these IP addresses can change. I want to resolve the IP address from a domain name and add the configuration:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
<AccessControls>
  <AccessControl name="security">
    <Rule action="permit" description="Allow access from A" order="100" remoteSubnet="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32" />
    <Rule action="permit" description="Allow access from B" order="200" remoteSubnet="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32" />
    <Rule action="permit" description="Allow access from C" order="300" remoteSubnet="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32" />
    <Rule action="deny" description="Deny access to everyone else" order="400" remoteSubnet="0.0.0.0/0" />
  </AccessControl>
</AccessControls>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I ended up writing a console application which gets called during the build which gets the IP address of the remove cloud service and checks whether it corresponds to what is in the configuration file.

If not, then I update it. Pretty straightforward.

Here is the build command:

```
$(SolutionDir)<MyProjectName>\$(OutDir)$(ConfigurationName)\MyExeName Update-FrontEnd-IPAddress-For-Azure-MicroService "$(SolutionDir)<AzureDeploymentProjectName>\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg"
```

The console application does:

```
        private static void HandleCheckRoleEnvironment(string[] args)
        {
            if (args[0] == "Check-Role-Environment")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found Command: Check-Role-Environment");

                if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable && !RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Running in Azure Cloud Environment");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NOT Running in Azure Cloud Environment");
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the code to update the config file:

```
        private static void ExecuteUpdateFrontEndIPAddressForAzureMicroService(string configFilePath)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(configFilePath))
            {
                return;
            }

            var ipAddressList = Dns.GetHostAddresses("MyDomainName");
            Console.WriteLine($"The IP address for MyDomainName is {ipAddressList[0].ToString()}");

            var correctValue = $"{ipAddressList[0].ToString()}/32";

            var document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(configFilePath);

            //Rule nodes
            var rules = document.ChildNodes[1].LastChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes;

            var rule = (from XmlNode p in rules
                        where p.Attributes["description"].Value == "Allow access from MyDomainName"
                        select p).FirstOrDefault();

            var ipAddressValue = rule.Attributes["remoteSubnet"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"The IP address in the config file is {ipAddressValue}");

            if (correctValue != ipAddressValue)
            {
                rule.Attributes["remoteSubnet"].Value = correctValue;
                document.Save(configFilePath);

                Console.WriteLine("The config file has been updated with the correct IP address.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The config file is upto date and will not be updated.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate role or an Azure Function that generates the new configuration and updates the service through REST: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460812.aspx